# Matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wonder if the following term 
$$
\ln\det\left(I+\text{diag}\left(d_1,\ldots,d_n\right)A\right),
$$
where $I$ is an identity matrix, $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ is a sequence of **binary** numbers, (taking the values $0$ and $1$), and $A$ is some symmetric matrix, can be rewritten in linear form as function of $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. That is to say, I want to rewrite the above term in the form
$$
\sum_id_if_i(A)
$$
where $f_i$ are some functions.

For example, in the simple scalar case (which I actually kind of motivated by) we have that
$$
\ln (1+d\cdot a) = d\cdot\ln(1+a).
$$
(EDIT) where $d$ is binary.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Your last equality is somewhat suspicions...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez As I said at the beginning, $d$ is binary. If $d=0$ then $ln(1) = 0 = 0\cdot\ln(1+a)$. If $d=1$ then $\ln(1+a) = 1\cdot\ln(1+a)$.

Comment: Are you working on information theory?

Comment: @LordSoth No...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $d_1 = 1$ and the rest of $d_i$s are zero. We have $\sum_i d_i f_i(A) = f_1(A)$. Directly evaluating the determinant, we obtain, $f_1(A) = \log(1+a_{11})$. Similarly, by setting $d_i = 1$ and $d_j = 0,\,j\neq i$, we obtain $f_i(A) = \log(1+a_{ii})$. Hence, we have the $\log\det$ equal to $\sum_id_i\log(1+a_{ii})$. A contradiction for a general selection for $d_i$s now easily follows (as our result depends only on the diagonal elements of $A$), i.e. you cannot find such a decomposition.

Comment: I see, thanks..